# Code.LoadError on import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I put import this on the `config.exs` file:

```
use Mix.Config
import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"
```

or

```
import_config "#{Mix.env()}.exs"
```

And when I try to run `mix test` it's complaining this:

```
mix test                                    
** (Code.LoadError) could not load /Users/romenigld/workspace/elixir/ebooks/issues/config/test.exs
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:1147: Code.find_file/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:706: Code.eval_file/2
    (mix) lib/mix/config.ex:187: anonymous fn/2 in Mix.Config.__import__!/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1925: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (mix) lib/mix/config.ex:186: Mix.Config.__import__!/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:232: Code.eval_string/3
```

It's a bug or I need to do something different?

Comment: You need to create a file `test.exs` in `config` directory in the first place. Also, you probably should stop suspecting it _to be a bug_ when you are writing code you barely understand what is supposed to do.

Comment: I already have the tests files.

I saw this on ebook, thank's for reply!

Comment: These test files have nothing to do with **`config/test.exs`** configuration file you instruct mix to load.

Comment: ok, I understand it's like some configuration like the Rspec.

Comment: It has nothing in common with `Rspec`. It is a pure application config.

Comment: I want to say I do some config like these using RSpec before. 
That's ok.... thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How `import_config/1` works

From [Mix.Config#import_config/1](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Config.html#import_config/1):

> Imports configuration from the given file or files.
>
> [...]
>
> If path_or_wildcard is not a wildcard but a path to a single file, then that file is imported; in case the file doesn't exist, an error is raised.
>
> If path/wildcard is a **relative** path/wildcard, it will be expanded relatively to the directory the current configuration file is in.

### How `Mix.env/0` works

From [Mix#env/0](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html#env/0):

> Returns the Mix environment.

When your application starts it will read the value from the environment varialbe `MIX_ENV` or set `:dev` if the environment variable is not set. [Combare implementation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/b711d08463ed32196c34eaf484380920d39e5597/lib/mix/lib/mix/state.ex#L14).

The task that runs when you call `mix test` [tells Mix](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/b711d08463ed32196c34eaf484380920d39e5597/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/test.ex#L132) to default to the `:test` environment through the [`@preferred_cli_env` attribute](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html#module-attributes).

### Combining `import_config/1` and `Mix.env/1`

Having a line of code equivalent to

```
import_config "#{Mix.env()}.exs"
```

will be evaluated at compile time (when running `mix test` for the first time) to

```
import_config "test.exs"
```

As the path is *relative* it will look for the file `test.exs` in the same directory where the file that contains the call to `import_config` is located.

In your case that is `/Users/romenigld/workspace/elixir/ebooks/issues/config/` so you have to create a valid config file in `/Users/romenigld/workspace/elixir/ebooks/issues/config/test.exs` and also for all other environments your application should run in (probably `dev` and `prod`).

You can get around creating config files for all environments by checking the environment before you call `import_config`:

```
unless Mix.env() == :prod do
  import_config("#{Mix.env()}.exs")
end
```

Comment: This is a better explanation @J. Random Coder.
Thank's!

Comment: @rld Please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer.

Comment: That's great! I think you might not be aware of the difference between upvoting and accepting an answer. Have a look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) or read more about [accepting an answer in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Please don't feel pushed to accept my answer, I'm just trying to be as helpful as I can.

Comment: Wow sorry, I never do that..
It's a lot of stuff here and I don't know everything.
Thank's for this help!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I could shed some light on the mechanics here on SO.